# I don't know where to get the right dll for using Microsoft.directx.direct3d (June or August 2007) for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, directx

Title says it all, i need the specific Microsoft.directx.direct3d DLL made in June or August 2007. Reason being is because the others do not have references for a Vector4. I have looked on google for about a hour now and tried others but they do not have a reference for a Vector4. I found the directx SDK made in June but when i extract it all it contains is project database files (.pdb files). I was hoping that someone could help me.
Thank you for reading.

This is for C# if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DirectX 9.0c from August 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13287) can be located there. Enjoy.

Throwing my two cents in here, I always advocate for trying to move towards newer technologies and since they made changes to the DX SDK, such as moving towards [DirectXMath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is usually mutually beneficial for both developers and end users, so long as you have not already invested heavily in a legacy technology. Although much of the code is portable, with newer versions of DirectX you will have a nightmarish time rewriting your code to conform to new datatypes and procedures.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, i have downloaded and installed the SDK but where can i find the dll file to add to the references in my C# project?

Comment: Look in the directory in which you installed the SDK you downloaded.

Comment: Yes, but there are tonnes of DLLs, how am i supposed to know which is the right one?